# Can I try Ubuntu without affecting any of my existing files?

Tags: installation, cd

My windows 7 got corrupted and doesnt boot on my Dell 1558 studio laptop. Now I decided to try out ubuntu before i reinstall windows. I downloaded the 701 MB ubuntu 12.04 iso and created the cd on my desktop. Next I put the cd in my laptop and then press F2 to get to boot menu. Now select CD. Will I be able to start Ubuntu directly from CD without losing my existing music, photos and documents? Its very important for me to keep my work documents secured. So can i Start ubuntu without affecting any files from the CD and then install ubuntu fully on harddrive when I have backed up the files ?

Answer (score 4):

As indicated in step 2 of [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop), you can try Ubuntu from the CD without affecting your installed files or existing operating system, but you should expect running Ubuntu from this Live CD to be slower than it would when installed on the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can try Ubuntu without affecting anything. Once booted into the "live" desktop, you can even use Ubuntu to back up files/data from your Windows drive on to a USB, etc.

Once you are satisfied everything is backed up, you can click the Install Ubuntu icon in the live desktop, or boot with the "Install Ubuntu" option to finally install Ubuntu.